# How to correctly format datetime

Tags: python, datetime

We are struggling with formatting datetime in Python 3, and we can't seem to figure it out by our own. So far, we have formatted our dataframe to datetime, so that it should be `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`:

before

- 02-01-2011 22:00:00

after

- 2011-01-02 22:00:00

For some very odd reason, when datetime is

- 13-01-2011 00:00:00

it is changed to this

- 2011-13-01 00:00:00

And from there it's mixing months with days and is therefore counting months instead of days.

This is all of our code for this datetime formatting:

```
df['local_date']=df['local_date'] + ':00'
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.local_date)

df['local_date']=df['local_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

UPDATED CODE WHICH WORKS:

```
df['local_date']=df['local_date'] + ':00'
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.local_date.str.strip(), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['local_date']=df['local_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Can't reproduce error -- running `datetime.strptime('13-01-2011 00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` gives `'2011-01-13 00:00:00'`. Maybe the incorrect date is being used, or more information is needed?

Comment: What information do you need? @rassar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say for sure, but I believe this has to do with the warning mentioned in the [documentation of `to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime):

> **dayfirst** : boolean, default False
>   Specify a date parse order if arg is str or its list-likes. If True, parses dates with the day first, eg 10/11/12 is parsed as 2012-11-10. **Warning: dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first (this is a known bug, based on dateutil behavior)**.

I think the way to get around this is by explicitly pssing a format string to `to_datetime`:

```
df['local_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.local_date, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

This way it won't accidentally mix months and days (but it will raise an error if any line has a different format)

Comment: I receive this error: ValueError: time data ' 01-01-2011 01:00:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: You have a space in front of the `01`. Trim the string and see if this fixes it

Comment: @Buster3650 Do you actually have a space at the beginning of your data there?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Seems like there was some uneccessary space, but now it works. I have updated code to my post!

Comment: if you have white spaces, use .strip(): `df['local_date'] = df['local_date'].strip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

local_date = "13-01-2011 00:00"

local_date = local_date + ":00"
local_date = pd.to_datetime(local_date, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

local_date = local_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(local_date)
```

The output is:

```
 2011-01-13 00:00:00
```